# Converting a string separated by commas to a list of floats

Tags: python, list

In Python, I currently have a one element list of elements given like so:

```
x= ['1.1,1.2,1.6,1.7']
```

where each of the values are only separated by commas. I want to make this a list of floats, e.g like

```
x=[1.1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.7]
```

I've tried `x=[float(i) for i in x]` and `x=[float(i) for i in x.split()]`, but both return errors.

Comment: try `x[0].split(',')`?

Comment: `x` is a list, so you would need to access it via `x[0]`. Also you should provide the delimiter to the `split` call, e.g.: `x[0].split(',')`

Answer (score 6):

`x` is a list with one string, so to access that string you need `x[0]`. That string is comma-separated, so you need to specify the delimiter: `split(',')`. (Otherwise, `split()` tries to split a string on whitespace, [as described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).)

So you end up with:

```
[float(i) for i in x[0].split(',')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) like this:

```
list(map(float, x[0].split(',')))
```

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) takes a function (`float` in our case) and an iterable ( in our case this list: `x[0].split(',')`). `float` function is called for each item of our list `x[0].split(',')`

It is equivalent to this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[float(item) for item in x[0].split(',')]
```

Comment: In Python3+, `map` does not return a list, it returns a map object, you will have to convert it to a list

Comment: @IronFist Python 3 is not tagged in this question!

Comment: Neither Python2 is, so you must generalize your answer, plus you are referring to Python3 in your answer (linked to Python3 docs.)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by commas, and construct a `float` from each item:

```
[ float(item) for item in '1.1,2.3,5.1'.split(',') ]
```

Comment: OP has a different input

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are applying your `split()` function on a string and not the single element list. Use `x[0]` to ensure that. Also, pass a separator `,` to the `split()` function.

```
x = [float(i) for i in x[0].split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`x=[float(i) for i in x.split()]` is almost correct, except for two things. For one, you're not passing in anything to the `split()` function, so it's not going to split anything in your string (it would split only on whitespace, which your string does not have). You want to split by commas, so you have to pass a comma to it, like `x.split(',')`.

Second, seeing as `x` is defined by `x= ['1.1,1.2,1.6,1.7']`, which is a list containing a single string, you would have to refer to the string in the array with `x[0]`. The final code would look like this:

```
x = ['1.1,1.2,1.6,1.7']
floats = [float(i) for i in x[0].split(',')]
print(floats)
```

This outputs a list of floats: `[1.1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.7]`

If `x` were just a string, like `x = '1.1,1.2,1.6,1.7'`, then you would simply use `floats = [float(i) for i in x.split(',')]`.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks, I've corrected the terminology.

Comment: FYI "not going to split on anything" is not correct, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - no delimiter means it splits on whitespace instead.

Comment: @whrrgarbl Thank you, I'll make that change.